# Как создать бинарное дерево в с++

Tags: c++

не могу скомпилировать бинарное дерево. подскажите пожалуйста что нужно исправить в коде

```
#include <iostream>
struct tree{
            int data;
            tree *left, *right;
            };
using namespace std;
void create_tree(tree *&p, int n)
{
    if (n==0)
    p=NULL;
    else
    {
        p=new tree;
        cin>>p->data;
        int n, nl=n/2, nr=n-nl-1;
        create_tree(p->left, nl);
        create_tree(p->right, nr);
    }
}
int main ()
{
    int n;
    tree *root;
    cout<<"VVedi razmer: ";
    cin>>n;
    create_tree(root, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще лучше реализовывать бинарное дерево через класс. Класс - это новая совокупность определенного поведения. Класс гибче и разумнее.

Comment: Имхо создавать дерево лучше в классе, чтобы потом можно было удалить использованную память в деструкторе.

Comment: @MagnusMio, у структур же тоже деструкторы есть?

Answer (score 1):

В функции create_tree внутри блока else{} Вы объявляете уже видимую здесь переменную n. Попробуйте ее удалить. 
 int nl=n/2, nr=n-nl;

Comment: Иметь переменную с тем же именем можно, её нельзя инициализировать значением переменной из "внешнего" блока. В данном случае ТС вообще её не инициализирует.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вроде работает:

```
void create_tree(tree **p, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        *p = NULL;
    }
    else
    {

        tree *newP = new tree;
        cin >> newP->data;
        int 
            nl = n / 2, 
            nr = n - nl - 1;
        create_tree(&newP->left, nl);
        create_tree(&newP->right, nr);
        *p = newP;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    int n;
    tree *root;
    cout<<"VVedi razmer: ";
    cin>>n;
    create_tree(&root, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Сейчас вот так:

```
p=new tree;
cin>>p->data;
int n, nl=n/2, nr=n-nl-1;
create_tree(p->left, nl);
create_tree(p->right, nr);
```

а надо сделать вот так:

```
p=new tree;
cin>>p->data;
int n = -1, nl=n/2, nr=n-nl-1;
create_tree(p->left, nl);
create_tree(p->right, nr);
```

и все работает.